# How can we deploy our updated/new cordapp on running node without stopping node?

Tags: build.gradle, blockchain, corda

I want to make the node running and CorDapp deployment independent.
So whenever I we made any modifications on the code (in states, contracts or any other java part). 
How can we build the updated project into jar and directly update it in the node.

Comment: As far as deploying new cordapp is concerned, you would need to restart the node for your new jar to be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Flows and explicit contract upgrades can currently only be updated during node restarts, as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.corda.net/upgrading-cordapps.html#performing-flow-upgrades).

You can use [CorDapp distribution services](https://github.com/corda/corda-solutions/tree/master/bn-apps/cordapp-updates-distribution) to automate the distribution part, but every operator still needs to restart nodes manually.

Answer (score 0):

Presently it is not possible, the node has to be restarted in order to carry out the update.